# Android imageview not being recognized

Tags: java, android

I have an imageview in an activity that I am trying to use to display the first image in a list (which will be switched when another image is selected from a gallery)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />
```

now my R.java has the following code:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    public static Integer image1;
    public static Integer image2;
    public static Integer image3;
    public static Integer image4;
    public static Integer image5;
    public static Integer image6;
    public static Integer image7;
    public static Integer image8;
}
```

but eclipse doesn't like this and I am unable ot launch the application.

Similarly, I have a MyGallery class and an adapter that is responsible for manipulating these images, but the adapter cannot "see" these variables for some reason (despite them being public static).

Comment: Are you manually editing R.java yourself?

Comment: Editing R.java doesn't help you, ADT does that for you.
as per your XML, you should be having, `public static final int imageView1 = XXXXX;` under `class id` if not you have trouble in generating R.java, check if `Project > Build Automatically` is checked

Comment: Why do you hardcode the filename into XML? Just leave `android:src` empty and initialize it within your program as required

Comment: @codeMagic what's wrong?

Comment: @mangusta I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: @codeMagic I don't understand yours either

Comment: @mangusta at least we agree on something :) "Why do you hardcode the filename into XML?"...why not? "Just leave android:src empty and initialize it within your program as required "....what will this accomplish that the current code doesn't?

Comment: @codeMagic I don't pretend that my advice is going to solve his problem but at least it is better to modify image source dynamically within the program itself. It probably may even solve this question too, who knows ;P

Comment: @mangusta Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be difficult. I'm just trying to get the point across that if it doesn't work in xml then it isn't going to work in Java. The root of the problem needs to be discovered

Comment: By the way, those images within `R` file, they should be initialized by hex numbers i.e. resource addresses but they don't. I wonder why

Comment: @mangusta aha, now you are getting to the root of the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sdk generate an id for you, and that id is a way to access the resource, so it doesn't make sense to edit it and you shouldn't. Rebuild your project and then the SDK will generate the id. Just specify and id name in the `android:id="@+id/<idName>"` and the sdk will do its work, if you want to specify an image in the `ImageView` use the `src` property, like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a class and int is a primitive type. Change the Integers to int.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK will generate the R.java for you. There is no need to manually edit it.

If you're not editing the R.java, then you need the build the project. As at the moment, all of the variables have not been assigned to any value.

With regards to the SDK automating the R.java file:

If you import your images into the `/res/..` directories, the SDK will generate the static drawable class automatically.

Then in the XML, you can specify the source of the drawable item. If I imported an image, say, `myImage.png`, then the following code would be appropriate:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewExample"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myImage" />
```